# How to note if an indicated action has any future actions occur after it in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a single table with the following columns: User ID, Activity Date, and an indicator column. I'm trying to note if any rows with the indicator have other indicated actions occur after them grouped by each individual user.

Below is an example of what the table looks like and what the desired output (calculated column) is:
[image: Desired Output]

Any help on this DAX problem would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the for the latest indicated date for the `User ID` and check if it's after the current one.

```
HasLaterIndicators =
VAR LatestDate =
    CALCULATE (
        MAX ( Table[Activity Date] ),
        ALLEXCEPT ( Table, Table[User ID] ),
        Table[Indicator] = "X"
    )
RETURN
    IF ( Table[Indicator] = "X" && Table[Activity Date] < LatestDate, "Yes" )
```